# Как выполнить цикл еще раз в Parallel.For?

Tags: c#, tpl

Допустим я в 100 потоков качаю картинки. Если какая либо итерация вызвало исключение - как его повторить по новой?

```
Parallel.For(0, newLst.Count, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100 }, (i) =>
      {
           DownloadImage(newLst[i]);
      });
```

Answer (score 5):

Сделять `DownloadImageAsync`, который дергать не в `Parallel.For`, а просто ограничив число одновременно выполняемых задач, например с помощью такого кода:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Task<TTask>> ForEachAsync<TItem, TTask>(
        this IEnumerable<TItem> source, Func<TItem, Task<TTask>> selector, 
        int degreeOfParallelism)
    {
        Contract.Requires(source != null);
        Contract.Requires(selector != null);

        // We need to know all the items in the source before starting tasks
        var tasks = source.ToList();

        int completedTask = -1;

        // Creating an array of TaskCompletionSource that would holds
        // the results for each operations
        var taskCompletions = new TaskCompletionSource<TTask>[tasks.Count];
        for(int n = 0; n < taskCompletions.Length; n++) 
            taskCompletions[n] = new TaskCompletionSource<TTask>();

        // Partitioner would do all grunt work for us and split
        // the source into appropriate number of chunks for parallel processing
        foreach (var partition in 
            Partitioner.Create(tasks).GetPartitions(degreeOfParallelism))
        {
            var p = partition;

            // Loosing sync context and starting asynchronous 
            // computation for each partition
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (p.MoveNext())
                {
                    var task = selector(p.Current);

                    // Don't want to use empty catch . 
                    // This trick just swallows an exception
                    await task.ContinueWith(_ => { });

                    int finishedTaskIndex = Interlocked.Increment(ref completedTask);
                    taskCompletions[finishedTaskIndex].FromTask(task);
                }
            });
        }

        return taskCompletions.Select(tcs => tcs.Task);
    }
```

Теперь можно будет сделать так:

```
var tasks = newLst.ForEachAsync(n => DownloadImageAsyncWithRetry(n, retryCount), 100).ToList()
```

И логику ретраинга просто впихнуть в `DownloadImageAsyncWithRetry`:

```
public Task<Result> DownloadImageAsyncWithRetry(input)
{
  var tsk = DownloadImageAsync(input);

  // Тут все зависит от того, каким именно образом определяется неудача.
  // Если это исключение, то вешаем ContinueWith, если это код возврата,
  // то проверяем его и пробуем повторить запрос.
}
```

Да, `Parallel.For` в этом случае идея - не очень, поскольку он предназначен прежде всего для CPU Intensive операций, а здесь явно IO Intensive. В этом случае логично сделать сам метод асинхронным, который будет дергать асинхронный API для загрузки картинок.

З.Ы. Код ForEachAsync взять [отсюда](https://github.com/SergeyTeplyakov/TplTipsAndTricks/blob/master/src/TplTipsAndTricks/ForEachAsync/TaskEx.cs).

Comment: ппц) столько методов о существовании которых я услышал и увидел впервые. Ладно на so ответ был. Но елки палки - как самому додуматься написать такое?

Comment: На самом деле, нужно просто двигаться постоянно вперед. Пусть и не быстро, но постоянно. И все это придет. Это ведь просто еще один паттерн: есть проблема - нужно запустить сколько-то асинхронных задач и потом ограничить их количество. С retry-ами - аналогично. Потом нужно просто скомбинировать эти проблемы в одном решении.

Comment: @Radzhab *"Ладно на so ответ был."* -- вы можете его перевести и опубликовать здесь.